# Hyperledger Fabric transactions are too slow

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I configured my Hyperledger Fabric network with 2 peers under 1 org and 2 couchdb, 1 each peer.
I am seeing that when I do a transaction, it takes some time to do it, sometimes around 1 second. For me it's too much time, it should be just some ms.

I have a simulator that is able to insert around 30k samples into the blockchain but it runs very slow because sometimes a transaction takes 1s, so you can imagine that with a such amount of data it takes a lot.
How can I solve this? Is Fabric able to handle more transaction than this?

What I have noticed and it seems wrong to me is that:

Using Fauxton to see inside couchdb, if I upload 300 samples on the blockchain, I see 300 blocks created. Could this be a problem? I know that a block should encapsulate more transaction, but my blockchains seems not to do this. How to solve?

Another thing that I have noticed is that I did not configure any endorsment policy. Should I do it and should it make it faster? How to do this?

And, finally: there is the possibility that couchdb is slowing down the network? How to disable it?

Comment: Yes it will affect. See more info on Batch size / Timeout at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/config_update.html?highlight=batch%20size#editing-a-config

Comment: Performance of a blockchain platform can be affected by many variables such as transaction/payload size, block size, network size/latency, hardware, etc etc - see more in the docs on this https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/whatis.html?highlight=performance#performance-and-scalability  ..

Comment: I know that this can affect the network. I am asking, basing on my configuration, what should I change first and how

Comment: On those settings, you may mix these two values as you would like - batch timeout must > 0 in the decoded config.json..  If your batch timeout is too small, then your orderer may never process transactions fast enough to fill a block to max message count before the timer expires.  Whichever parameter is exceeded first will trigger a block to be created.

Comment: Generally, reducing batch timeout will decrease latency, but at the expense of total throughput.  Conversely, increasing max message count will generally increase total throughput at the expense of transaction latency. You should find a balance that works well for your particular situation. In addition to the channel update doc link I sent you, see also this blog for an example of changing https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-fabric-updating-channel-configs-45082a5dc9b2

Comment: Per some of the comments, please upload an example of your write data.  If you have varied payload size, please share the median, or a few to define a range

Answer (score -1):

Two hidden complexities can impact performance

1. The complexity of your query, per record type. It’s important to form a performance histogram based on object types
2. Whether your data structure is pre-ordered to suiting the hashing algorithm. If not, you’ll experience a slight bit for drag if you object size is large.